# Tag Wiki Edits: Spam or Not?

Tags: discussion, stack-overflow, review, spam

I was reviewing suggested edits recently and came across these two tag edits, made by the same person:

1. [flask tag wiki suggested edit](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/2907312)
2. [django tag wiki suggested edit](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/2907300)

Both edits were rejected by me, but were ultimately approved by the community.

What stood out to me was the edit comment for each. One of the edit comments reads:

> link to flask usage examples on Sourcegraph (disclaimer: I'm one of the creators of Sourcegraph.)

The other edit comment is similar. As I was reviewing, I thought the edits were borderline spam, so I investigated further. From the [Sourcegraph About page](https://sourcegraph.com/about):

> Sourcegraph makes it easier to find the information you need: documentation, examples, usage statistics, answers, and more.

From what I understand, Sourcegraph is a tool to do code analysis; the tag wiki edits referenced above seem to just link to the Sourcegraph analysis of the Django and Flask source code.

**My questions**

Was I correct to reject the above edits as spam? If I was wrong, why are the edits not considered spam?

Comment: I'd hardly recommend that mess as "usage examples"...

Comment: I think Wikipedia's rule of: *if a thing is important enough, **other** people will write about it* is apropos. Of course there will be exceptions, but a link should point to content that is canonical and/or phenomenal, and it certainly doesn't seem to be the case in this situation.

Comment: For the record, the edits in question have been removed: [Flask tag wiki rollback](http://stackoverflow.com/revisions/3625311/8), and [Django tag wiki rollback](http://stackoverflow.com/revisions/3607538/32).

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I say it's spam. I would be reluctant to accept third party links in general. Otherwise tag wikis will end up as big link directories.

The site in question seems non-commercial for now, but that doesn't mean it's not spam. It looks like a github crawler without much useful content. The disclaimer seems to indicate the users good intent - but that could also have been the intention of including it. The link seems kind of promotional.

Both tag wikis already link to their official documentations with many examples. I see no reason to link to other external sites, unless 'Sourcegraph' is something well known and accepted in the those frameworks' communities (which I guess it's not). Should sourcegraph link from every tag wiki to their site just because they indexed some random code snippets from github? Of course not.

Comment: The community seems to agree that the edits are spam.

Answer (score 2):

Spam primarily refers to blatant advertising/publicity for products and services. If it's a link to a legitimate resource and nothing is stated about "visit my site!", then it isn't spam.

https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/144802/217361

In this case, that website appears to be promotional and not directly relevant.  I would just accept a link if it leads to an SE question or another site with adequate information (including Wikipedia).

Comment: a link just existing says "visit me", and that is a commercial website, and the content of dubious value.

Comment: @AndrewBarber: Ah, okay.  I thought it had to look obvious at first glance.

Comment: No problem. Your answer is not bad here as a general answer, but in this case I think those edits were spammy.

Comment: @AndrewBarber: Okay.  That's good for me to keep in mind when doing my own peer reviews off-site.

Comment: @AndrewBarber Shouldn't you *..like..* rollback those edits since they were indeed spam? :)

Comment: @asheeshr Why do you people keep encouraging me to feed my addiction for deleting content? ;-)

Comment: @AndrewBarber: I feel the same about my flagging. :-)